# Polyglossia v1.46 modifies font family in header

Tags: header-footer, luatex, memoir, fontspec, polyglossia

This is my first question, please let me know if I am doing something incorrectly!

After updating `polyglossia` to version `v1.46` (from 2019/11/15) there seems to be a clash with `memoir` to version `2019/11/15 v3.7i`. I am using LuaTeX version 1.10.0.

**EDIT: Just to clarify, it used to work (`memoir: 2018/12/12 v3.7h` and `polyglossia v1.45`).**

I am using the `memoir` built-in system for content in the header and footer. However, after the update, `\sffamily` has no effect on `\leftmark` (or on `\rightmark`). Other font-commands like `\bfseries` or `\color{red}` does work, however. The page number is unaffected and works as expected.

After removing one thing at a time from my preamble, the culprit turned out to be `polyglossia`. The text from the mark is set with the standard font instead of the sans (though in red as expected). However, if I comment-out the two `polyglossia`-lines everything behave as expected.

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{memoir}

% THIS SEEMS TO BE THE ISSUE
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}

% Pagestyle
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\headerfontX}{\color{red}\sffamily}
\makepagestyle{jtest}
\makeevenhead{jtest}{\headerfontX\leftmark}{}{}
\makeevenfoot{jtest}{}{\headerfontX\thepage{} of \thelastpage}{}
\makeatletter
\makepsmarks {jtest}{
  \createmark{chapter}{both}{nonumber}{}{}
}
\makeatother
\nouppercaseheads
\pagestyle{jtest}

% Dummy text
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{The Title of the Chapter}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Here is the result of the compilation (left is with `polyglossia`, right is without):

[image: Left is with polyglossia, right is without]

EDIT: Here is the result of compiling exactly the same MWE (i.e. *with* `polyglossia`) with the old package versions (left) and new (right):

[image: Left is with old packages, right is with new]

So before updating it works as expected.

Why is *polyglossia* affecting the **font** of the mark at all? And why does `\bfseries` work, but not `\sffamily`?

Is this a bug in the new release of `memoir` and/or `polyglossia`?

Thanks!

(As a sidenote: It is possible to make a workaround. Removing `\createmark{chapter}...` and instead re-defining the chaptermark by `\renewcommand\chaptermarksn[1]{\headerfontX}` fixes font of the `\leftmark`. If the mark was numbered, it would be fixable by adding the font as a prefix in `\createmark`.)

---

**UPDATE:** This is not related to `memoir`. As pointed out by `daleif` in the comments, the bug is also present if using the `book` class.

Comment: This is not `memoir` related as this `book` example gives the same problem: `\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\makeatletter
\def\@evenhead{\thepage\hfil\sffamily\leftmark}%
\def\@oddhead{{\sffamily\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}%
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{The Title of the Chapter}
\lipsum
\end{document}`

Comment: Thanks for that example! That is indeed true. As in the memoir-case, the old version of polyglossia works as expected without this problem.

Answer (score 6):

`polyglossia` resets the font family when `\foreignlanguage` is used:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
{\color{red}\sffamily Abc  \foreignlanguage{english}{Abc}} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

As `polyglossia` surrounds the header with such `\foreignlanguage` you get your output.

With `babel` it works fine:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
{\color{red}\sffamily Abc  \foreignlanguage{english}{Abc}} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! However, it used to work? I have just made a test with *memoir* version 2018/12/12 v3.7h and *polyglossia* from 2019/10/27, and there I get the output I expect? Should I instead make this point into a new question?

Comment: I don't know which package changed but I think the behaviour of polyglossia is questionable. Open an issue at the github page. Why don't you want to use babel instead?

Comment: Erh, `memoir` does not include `\foreignlanguage` anywhere, it is `polyglossia` messing with things.

Comment: @daleif ah sorry, it was a bit late and as leftmark  is changed with babel too I thought it was memoir.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer , it does indeed seem questionable. I will open an issue. I have always used polyglossia with luatex as I "was told" to do that (and I typically have to switch between Danish and English). But I will definitely give babel a go (again)!

Answer (score 1):

This is confirmed to be a bug in `polyglossia v1.46` as a side-effect of another fix.

See https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/355 .

---

**Workaround 1**

If just the chapter title is desired. Then replace

```latex
\makeatletter
\makepsmarks {jtest}{
  \createmark{chapter}{both}{nonumber}{}{}
}
\makeatother
```

by

```latex
\renewcommand\chaptermarksn[1]{\headerfontX}
```

---

**Workaround 2**

In the case where the chapter number is included in the header. Now, itcan be done using just the `memoir` marks and adding the font command as prefix:

```latex
\makeatletter
\makepsmarks {jtest}{
  \createmark{chapter}{both}{shownumber}{\headerfontX}{:~}
}
\makeatother
```

This of course also applies to other numbered marks.

---

**Workaround 3**

As @UlrikeFischer suggested, use `babel` instead of `polyglossia`.