# KOMA-Script "pageheadfoot" font not taking \sffamily

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, sans-serif, scrlayer-scrpage

I've been typing a document for a few months now and I'm using the class scrreprt. I've just noticed that the header font, which used to be sans serif, has reverted back to serif because the koma font "pageheadfoot" is not taking the `\sffamily` command (and neither `\ttfamily`). I reduced the problem to this MWE:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX spellcheck = it_IT

\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{italian}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sffamily \bfseries}
\KOMAoptions
  { headsepline=on }
\ohead
  { \headmark }
\ofoot*
  { \pagemark }

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{Section 2}
\lipsum[6-9]
\section{Section 3}
\lipsum[10-12]
\end{document}
```

However the output is what you can see here:

[image: MWE]

UPDATE - I've figured a workaround by putting `\sffamily` within `\markboth` and `\markright`... I don't know whether it is "clean" or "cheating" though.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/516853/2388. I would suggest to use babel instead.